# how to embed an image in a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I know it is possible to embed an image in a Tkinter text widget, but I've been unable to find some simple example code.
Specifically, I need to embed a jpg, so according to the docs I think I need to use the photoimage class

I tried to use this:

```
  img=PhotoImage ( file=imgfn )
  text.image_create(image=img)
```

where imgfn is the image filename, and text is my text widget,
but I get "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file ..."

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PhotoImage` only handles `GIF` and `PGM/PPM` files.  In order to use `JPEG` with Tkinter, you can use the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to create a `PhotoImage`.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = Image.open("yourimg.jpg")
photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Alternatively you could just one of the other supported formats for `PhotoImage` if possible.

Comment: works perfectly - thank you (BTW, my error: .image_create needs 2 args, I neglected the 1st (insertion point): text.image_create(INSERT, image=photoImg)