# Tkinter create_image not displaying

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an app to display a grid of images, much like the main screen of iPhoto or other similar programs. To do so, I set up a Canvas, and iterate through a list of filenames, creating a PhotoImage from each, and displaying them on the canvas:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(self.bottomFrame, width = 700, height = 470, bg = "Red")
self.canvas.pack()

for i, filename in enumerate(image_list):
    photo_image = PhotoImage(filename)
    self.canvas.create_image(100*(round(i/4)+1), 100*(i+1), image = photo_image)
    self.labelList.append(photo_image)
```

The labelList is an attribute of the Application class, and the image_list is populated with filenames of .gif photos. When I run the app, however, no images display. I know the canvas is there, because a red rectangle shows up, but there are no images on it.

What am I missing here - I've scrolled through endless pages of discussion looking for results and haven't found any that work.

Comment: What type of file is `filename`?

Comment: "The application must keep a reference to the image object." from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method. Sure you did?

Comment: @pythonm -- the reference should be kept in `self.labelList`.  No problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
photo_image = PhotoImage(filename)
```

should be

```
photo_image = PhotoImage(file=filename)
```

---

Otherwise, you just set `name`, since the `__init__` function of `PhotoImage` looks like this:

```
__init__(self, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw)
```

---

Also note that `PhotoImage` can only handle GIF and PGM/PPM files. If you want other file types, you have to use PIL ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413266/how-to-embed-an-image-in-a-text-widget)).

Comment: argv! That's a seemingly silly way for them to define the function. (+1)

Comment: @mgilson Yeah, it is not intuitive at all. The main problem is that you don't get any feedback at all if you fall into this trap other than that no image is shown...

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Thank you! Worked perfectly. Now I'm just irritated that it was that simple...